# How to host Adonis js app in Heroku hosting [Adonis js ]

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect, heroku-enterprise

I tried to host my web-app but it shows an an error.I followed all this steps

Download and install the Heroku CLI.

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

**$ heroku login**
**Clone the repository**
Use Git to clone knv-webapp source code to your local machine.
**$ heroku git:clone -a knv-webapp**
**$ cd knv-webapp**
Deploy your changes
Make some changes to the code you just cloned and deploy them to Heroku using Git.

**$ git add .**
**$ git commit -am "make it better"**
**$ git push heroku master**

And my error
[image: See here]

[image: Logs]